# Regex for amount as you type?

Tags: ios, regex, uitextfield

My allowed amount format is

xxxxxx
 - or - 
xxxxxx.xx

- fractions are optional
- max 6 decimal places for whole part
- max 2 decimal places for fractional part
- dot delimits whole and fraction part
- If first char is zero, only a dot is allowed after that.
- Only allow one dot
- Donot allow a zero at second decimal palce in fraction ,if the first char is also zero.

There are a lot of questions for amount regex strings (independently of platform.
However the problem is all of them are provided with the assumption they will be used to validate the amount string ONLY after it is fully typed.

But what I need is a regex that will serve as a filter for WHAT you can type WHILE you type. That means, given the requirements at the top, you should be able to type this into a textfield and the validation logic should report that what was typed in matches reges fully.

0
0.
0.01

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> There are a lot of questions for amount regex strings (independently of platform. However the problem is all of them are provided with the assumption they will be used to validate the amount string ONLY after it is fully typed.

From this I am inferring that you have no problem creating a Regex that satisfies your requirements, only problem is implementing it.

In order to filter unwanted input while typing you need to place some filtering logic inside of `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let regex = "^(?=\\d*\\.?\\d*$)(?!0\\d|\\d{7}|\\d+\\.\\d(0|\\d\\d))"
    guard var amountString = textField.text else {
        return false
    }
    amountString += string

    if amountString.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) == nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Inherit `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class, assign the delegate of the `UITextField` to `self` and you're good to go.

Oh and as a bonus I tried to do it without Regex. Seems to work. Go for the first one unless you have something against Regex.

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard var amountString = textField.text else {
        return false
    }
    amountString += string

    if !isNumber(amountString) {
        return false
    }

    if (amountString.first == "0") {
        if amountString.count == 2 && amountString != "0." {
            return false
        }
    }

    if let indexOfDecimal = amountString.index(of: ".") {
        let decimalString = String((String(amountString[(indexOfDecimal)...])).dropFirst())

        if (decimalString.count > 2 || decimalString == "00") {
            return false
        }
    } else if (amountString.count > 6 && string != ".") {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func isNumber(_ s: String) -> Bool {
    return Float(s) != nil
}
```

Comment: Oh I knew about the delegate callback. But I am perplexed how can your code work (it does)...when you do amountString += string..What if it's a deletion? We are still adding the empty string to current string. Why?

Comment: amountString is only used for the logic that makes sure the input is of the correct format. It actually doesn't change the actual text in the textfield. All we need to do is return true or false depending on whether we approve of the input i.e. return true if it's acceptable, else false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather intuitive method for performing such validations in a "check as you type" scenario:

```
^(?=\d*\.?\d*$)(?!0\d|\d{7}|\d+\.\d(0|\d\d))
```

The positive lookahead in the first part matches the general pattern of what is acceptable, and the negative lookahead in the second part enforces your rules.